# How do I select a subset of elements from a STL list?

Tags: c++, list, extract, sublist

I have an STL list of pointers to a Person class, list L. The instances of the class have three properties Name, Age, Weight, and Height. They are of type string, int, int, double respectively. I want to extract a subset of the list where Name assumes a value, say, "John" and perform operations on the sublist. Alternately, I could perform operations on the sublist without first extracting it from the main list. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: [iter::slice plug](https://github.com/ryanhaining/cppitertools#slice)

Comment: Traverse the list, make a new list with the Person objects that meet your requirements?

Comment: So what is your actual problem?

Comment: Suppose you want to take all people named John and remove the John entry in the list with the minimum value of weight. Repeat the process for every unique name.

Comment: Pretty good odds that the cost of building the sublist and then iterating the sublist will be higher than simply operating on the list. Unless you have some groovy ordering scheme you haven't shared, you have to iterate the whole list to make sure you have all of the matching elements in the sublist. Might as well just perform the operation on the elements as you find them.

Comment: Unless you intend to cache and reuse that sublist, that is. In that case, may I recommend `std::shared_ptr`? Why the heck are you using a list of pointers anyway?